# StreamBuilder snapshot has data but does return not update with intended Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, stream-builder

Using Firebase to successfully login to an app. On that login page the submit function is called with correct credentials using
_firebase.signInWithEmailAndPassword.
Snackbar shows me I have been successful:

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _LoginState();
  }
}

class _LoginState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final _form = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _firebase = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  var _enteredEmail = '';
  var _enteredPassword = '';

  void _submit() async {
    final isValid = _form.currentState!.validate();
    if (isValid) {
      _form.currentState!.save();
      try {
        final _userCredentials = await _firebase.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: _enteredEmail, password: _enteredPassword);
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).clearSnackBars();
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            const SnackBar(content: Text('login success'))); // this works perfectly
    
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).clearSnackBars();
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(content: Text(error.message ?? 'login failed')));
      }
    }
  }
```

Back in main.dart, In the Streambuilder block, snapshot.hasData is true as a consequence of the successful login but the return is not returning anything: just left hanging on the login screen. However, if I restart the app, the data/token had been cached (from the previous successful login) because the app immediately opens at the logged in screen, e.g. return is now working.

```
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const CoeApp());
}

class CoeApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const CoeApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Update Your Information',
        theme: ThemeData(
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
          useMaterial3: true,
        ),
        
        home: StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
            builder: (BuildContext ctx, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              print("Snapshot data: ${snapshot.data}");
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                print("Snapshot Error: ${snapshot.error}");
                return const Text("Error");
              }
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                //print(" snapshot has data..xx.");
                return const Text("This doesn't happen and it should!"); 
                // ActionsPage(); // normally reachable but replaced for debugging
              }
              return const LandingPage();
            } //const
            ));
  }
}
```

Is there anything obviously wrong with this code. Thanks

Comment: your code looks fine to me. I think It is returning you that text but it is in the corner of your screen therefore you are not able to see it. try this:

if (snapshot.hasData) {
//print(" snapshot has data..xx.");
return const Center(child:  Text("This doesn't happen and it should!",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 45,color: Colors.red),),);
// ActionsPage(); // normally reachable but replaced for debugging
}

Comment: Thank you but that isn't the issue. If I restart the emulator that text appears (or the ActionsPage also works if not commented out) It literally doesn't update the display - regardless as to what is on the end of the return statement.

Comment: thats odd. stream builder doesn't need to use setState((){}); to update state as it updates state itself. did you tried flutter clean?

Comment: I think i found your issue! as you are using stateless Widget as parent widget thats why it isn't rebuilding or acting as builder. please try changing from stateless to stateful widget

Comment: Really appreciate your help Muzammil. I tried all you suggested but I think the problem was in the emulators. I started a whole new app which also failed initially but I reset all the data in both Android and iOS emulators and got past the problem now.

Comment: I am happy that your problem got resolved Kevin. Just always try to help :). Happy coding bro.